# Which sorting algorithm produces these steps?

Tags: sorting

This was a multiple-choice question in an exam today, and (at least) one of the answers should be true, but to me they all look wrong.

The sorting steps are:
5 2 6 1 3 4
4 2 6 1 3 5
4 2 5 1 3 6
4 2 3 1 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6

The available answers were: Bubble Sort, Insertion Sort, Selection Sort, Merge Sort and Quick Sort.

Comment: maybe interesting? http://visualgo.net/sorting :)

Comment: It cannot be selection or bubble sort as they would move the highest value to the end on the first pass.

Comment: what I can't make sense of, is that the 4 is swapped with 5, but the 3 is swapped with 5.

Comment: @RyanVincent easy: try with every 6 possible pivot. None allow you to keep `6 1` like that.

Comment: I would be really interested in seeing what the result of the exam is, and why.

Comment: are you sure you got the steps right?

Comment: @Falkha Why you accepted the wrong answer?

Comment: @MegaTron are you actually convinced a quicksort can produce that series of steps?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, I'm sure. To check I create a test program where I implemented quicksort algorithm and then debug it. The answer is Quick Sort. If you want I can show you implementation. I used C# for that

Comment: @MegaTron please do add your implementation to your answer, I am really curious to see what I missed.

Comment: @njzk2 I can't do it now. I'll show you tomorrow, but it is something like https://gist.github.com/lbsong/6833729

Comment: @MegaTron: The output doesn't even look remotely similar: https://ideone.com/RfUldP

Comment: @MegaTron logging the consistent states of the array: https://ideone.com/HGIBnx , the output is consistent with my demonstration of the choices of pivots.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

None of them.

- bubble sort: no. After k steps, the last k elements should be the k largest, sorted.
- insertion sort: no. After k steps, the k first elements should be sorted.
- selection sort: no. After k steps, the k first elements should be the s smallest, sorted.
- merge sort: no. After k steps, a value can only have moved `2^k - 1` places. (5 moves 5 places at k=1)
- quick sort: no. Whatever the pivot is, 1 and 6 being the extreme values, they can stay in this initial position.

On the quick sort: To make it clear that it is not possible, lets enumerate the results of each pivot for the first step:

- 5 : `[2134] - 5 - [6]`. (2134 may be in any order)
- 2 : `[1] - 2 - [5634]`
- 6 : `[52134] - 6`
- 1 : `1 - [52634]`
- 3 : `[21] - 3 - [564]`
- 4 : `[213] - 4 - [56]`

One obvious way of seeing that all those are incompatible with the OP's output is that in each case, the `1` is before the `6`, no matter how you implement the pivot or the partition.

Comment: There's variants of each of these algorithms that dont meet the criteria. Note that the sample input is missing only a single swap to be a valid insertion sort. (right to left + swapping in place rather than using a reference)  That being said, I can't think of any variant that matches the inputs.

Comment: insertion sort uses insertions, not swaps.

Comment: The question says: and (at least) one of the answers should be true. There is a easy way to check, just create a program that will be sort `5 2 6 1 3 4` used each algorithms and debug it.

Comment: @MegaTron, That can easily be tried with the `visualgo` link. It is interesting as none of them match as far as I can tell. ;-/ Bubble sort and insertion sort definitely don't match the first pass as 6 would be last and 1 would be first.

Comment: @njzk2: The easiest way to shift from an unordered range to the end of another range is to swap.

Comment: @MooingDuck but that requires one swap for each item you jump over.

Comment: @njzk2: One for each item bigger than your current max, yes. Which produces output _almost_ identical to that of the problem: https://ideone.com/wgvl0n

Comment: @MooingDuck that looks more like a selection sort, but without the temporary max variable

Answer (score 3):

I think that is a Quick sort. Here we can see the following steps:

- A random selection of the reference element in the array (pivotValue), with respect to which reorders the elements of the array.
- Move all of the values that are larger than the reference to the right, and all the values that the lower support left
- Repeat algorithm for unsorted the left and right side of the array, while each element will not appear on its position

Why I think so:

It definitely isn't a Bubble Sort because it compares the first two elements of the array beginning so, the first step should be `2 5 6 1 3 4`

It isn't a Insertion Sort because it's a sequential algorithm. In the first step we see that compared the first and the last element

It isn't a Selection Sort because it find the lowest value and move it to the top so, the first step should be `1 5 2 6 3 4`

It isn't a Merge Sort because the array is divided into two subarrays. In this case we see interaction "first" and "second" parts

Comment: It can't be quick sort. The first swap would only happen if it chose 5 for the pivot, but if so, the next step must be swapping the 6 and the 3. Instead, it swaps the 6 and the 5 again, which makes no sense for a quicksort. If you can figure out the pivots that make sense, that would prove it could be a quicksort, but I don't think there's any pivots that would result in those swaps.

Comment: It almost looks like a really lucky insertion sort running biggest to lowest, but it's missing a 4/3 swap in the middle :/

Comment: @ Mooing Duck  It is not insertion sort because after the first step we will have 2 5 6 1 3 4. Try to write the code and debug it

Comment: I said biggest to lowest. Step 1: It searches left to right, swapping any numbers biggest than the last with the last position, thus swapping the 5/4, so we're good here. Then it finds the 6, and does the 5/6 swap, so far so good. Then it would start the second pass, see the 4 is bigger than the 3, and swap, but this is missing. Then it would find the 5 bigger than the three and swap, which we see. Then it would start third pass, starting with the 4/1 swap, which is there. All subsequent passes would do nothing because it's done. It's literally only one step missing.

Answer (score -2):

To solve this all you have to do is make a function for each sort algorithm but include a statement to print the array out after each swap. Then apply your print friendly sort algorithms to the initial array [5 2 6 1 3 4] and see which sort method produces the same output. Additionally, this will help you compare all the different methods.